# Get unfiltered Java FX TableView columns

Tags: java, javafx, filter, tableview

I have a TableView with rows that are filtered depending on what you type in a TextField which searches all the columns , using this piece of code :

```
FilteredList<CommandeFX> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, p -> true);

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(commande -> {
            // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            // Compare first name and last name of every person with filter text.
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (String.valueOf(commande.getCodeCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true;
                 // Filter matches first name.

            } else if (String.valueOf(commande.getCMD()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getClient()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {                                  
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getFournisseur()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getQuantite()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getPrixCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getSommeProperty()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getResteCommandeProperty()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getDateCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getDateReception()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getModified()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getValide()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }

            return false; // Does not match.
        });
    });


    // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
    SortedList<CommandeFX> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);    

    // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableCommandes.comparatorProperty());
    // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
    tableCommandes.setItems(sortedData);
```

No problem so far, I also use these lines of code to change the styling (color in my case) of certain columns depending on a column value ( the column is titled "reste") :

```
reste.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<CommandeFX, Number>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            setText(empty ? "" : getItem().toString());
            setGraphic(null);

            TableRow<BonFX> currentRow = getTableRow();

            if (!isEmpty()) {

                if(Float.valueOf((float) item)>0)
                    currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");

            }
        }
    };
});
```

When I filter the rows, say I had three rows all colored in red, after filtering I have one row left displayed and colored in red, great ! The problem is the two invisible rows are still shown in red although they're not displayed! How can disable styling rows that are visible anymore ?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your row is empty then set its default color:

```
reste.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<CommandeFX, Number>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            TableRow<BonFX> currentRow = getTableRow();

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
                setGraphic(null);
                currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:(****your default color****)");
            } else {
                setText(getItem().toString());
            }

            if (!isEmpty()) {
                if (Float.valueOf((float) item) > 0) {
                    currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");
                }

            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much !